# "Recommend a Friend" feature for Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Symantec have been busy laying off all my previous workmates in Australia, turns out development is cheaper in Estonia.

I have been busy sending a few of them Careers invites.

I would like to add LinkedIn-style recommendations to my old colleagues, to help them in their job hunting.

---

The way I see it, getting a generic invite to careers is way less impactful then getting a personalized message. I should be able to include my recommendation as part of the invite.

For example, add a text box on the invite with my recommendation:

> Sam Saffron would like to invite you
>   to Stack Overflow Careers:
>
> He also added a recommendation:
>
> "Fred is a waffle connoisseur, his
>   skills in waffledom are second to
>   none. If I were to embark on a Waffle
>   adventure, he would be the first person
>   I would hire."
>
> Once you sign up you will be able to
>   choose to display this recommendation
>   on your profile.
>
> Click here to create your accout...

---

I should be able to add a recommendation prior to sign-up or after sign-up.

Comment: [Elbonians](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1996-02-22/)?

Comment: Sad to hear that man. My old company too decided development was cheaper in Bulgaria than in Germany. Everyone related to development had to go. After so many years the managers still have learned nothing...

Comment: On the other hand, let's keep positive thinking. I read in the news last year that in Tallinn (Estonia capital) due to high unemployment some rents dropped to zero. The apartments were being given away with the only condition the tenant must come up for the utilities. Even a few new jobs there might make a difference even if only a slight one.

Comment: Nice idea, and the Careers team has been batting it around. Lots of implications in terms of how people interact with profiles, whether they are public, etc. It’s a big step into social, which Careers hasn’t been to date. Most of our design has been around letting *employers* find you, so we need to wrap our heads around the UX.

Answer (score 2):

I like the basic idea, but I don't think the recommendation should be limited to whoever happens to invite me to the site.

Recommendations should be a universal thing that all careers users can give each other.

Comment: Up until now they've been quite resistant to all requests to introduce the "buddy" feature - in one form of another. I however think it might be beneficial if done properly. After all recommendations are just another form of reputation, aren't they?

Comment: @Developer yeah. A colleague's (or even employer's!) recommendation is *really* relevant info for the hiring process